# how do i change default path for apache configuration files?

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, apache2

Does anyone know, how to change(or reinstall) default path for apache configuration files?

configuration file in

...

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf

/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

....

or something else

i'm working on ubuntu linux 13.04 with apt-get installed.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are after is the `-f` flag that let you specify a main configuration file at startup. It's explained in detail in [Starting Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/invoking.html) document section.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

All the configurations files are read by Apache when apache starts. Thus you can store your configuration files in sites-enabled/ and apache will read all the configuration files from there.

You can also append the following line in /etc/apache/apache2.conf:
    Include /home/user/directory-for-conf

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting as a service then go to the systemd unit location. Mine is `/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service`. However, changing this file is not advised because it is cleared on package updates. I had to create an override file:

```
sudo systemctl edit httpd  (note: can use httpd.service too)
```

After running this command, the terminal opened a blank window and I changed ExecStart.

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=<path-to-httpd> -f <new-path> -DFOREGROUND
```